# Callback executed to early when i create a index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, callback

my callback method executes to early. CreateIndexMaxFrame should start after CreateIndexFrame is done. But it starts while "CreateIndexFrame" is still indexing. Also the function `console.log("Done")` should executed when everthing is done. But it also starts to early.

```
createIndexFrame(dbObject, collectionName,function()
            {
                createIndexMaxFrame(dbObject, collectionName,function()
                {
                    io.emit('message', { text: "Fertig" });
                    db.close();
                    console.log("DONE");
                });
            });

function createIndexFrame(dbObject,collectionName, callback)
{
    dbObject.collection(collectionName).createIndex({frame:1, temp:-1},function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback();
    });
}

function createIndexMaxFrame(dbObject,collectionName, callback)
{
    dbObject.collection(collectionName).createIndex({maxFrame:-1},function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback();
    });
}
```

https://i.ibb.co/bPzK3Bq/callback.png [screenshot](https://ibb.co/hyDmMWh)

The screenschot is a log by Docker and will show the issue. Mongo_1 shows all MongoLogs. Fill_db_1 is the programm which execute createIndexFrame, createIndexMaxFrame.

As you can see MongoDB will create 2 Indexs parallel.

[conn5] = is createIndexFrame()

[conn2] = is createIndexMaxFrame()

Also the message "DONE" is alredy showing. Although createIndexMaxFrame is not finished.

Comment: Your indentation makes your code not so easy to read.

Comment: @TGrif sorry for that. but what do you need an information? thank you for your help